Spring Security Kerberos / SPNEGO To Active Directory
I am trying to add SSO to Active Directory using Spring Security Kerberos Support (Spring Boot 2.7). I have deployed the sample (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#samples-sec-server-win-auth) as a war file (in tomcat). When I hit the /hello url I always see AnonymousAuthenticationToken. I am trying to debug the flow to see what the problem might be. I tried to show the network traffic in the browser web developer tools but see nothing. I am setting a series of breakpoints to understand the flow and source of the problem. The break point in SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter show I never receive the "negotiate" header.
What is the code flow for the kerberos / Spnego authentication with the Spring security kerberos tools?
Thanks
